# Oauth with Grails is not working with Hotmail

Tags: grails, oauth

I want to fetch the user's details after login in to Hotmail by using SocialAuth with Grails.
For this at first I have register my Application like this (account.live.com).

```
Root Domain: www.localhostsocialtest.com (Deployee on localhost)
Redirect Urls: http://www.localhostsocialtest.com
```

In controller the redirect url is :"http://www.localhotsocialtest.com:8080/SocialAuthExample/SocialAuth/getToken"

But I have get error from microsoft.

```
Oops, there was a problem
The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The domain of the provided redirect URI must match the domain of the redirect URI registered for this app.
```

Answer (score 0):

The default http port is 80, but you appear to be running on 8080, so you either need to change `http://www.localhostsocialtest.com` to `http://www.localhostsocialtest.com:8080` or run on port 80